# Symfony - Unable to create new project using installer

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to learn Symfony but so far just keep getting hung up on installation and things other than the actual development of my app.

I try to create a new Symfony project on my Windows machine using the installer. I'm following the instructions exactly as it says [in the book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html). I can successfully download the `symfony.phar` but when I run:

```
php symfony.phar
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  Phar::mapPhar(symfony.phar): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in symfony.phar on line 9
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() symfony.phar:0
PHP   2. Phar::mapPhar() symfony.phar:9

Warning: Phar::mapPhar(symfony.phar): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in symfony.phar on line 9

Call Stack:
    0.0017     227224   1. {main}() symfony.phar:0
    0.0017     227920   2. Phar::mapPhar() symfony.phar:9

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'unable to open phar for reading "symfony.phar"' in symfony.phar:9
Stack trace:
#0 symfony.phar(9): Phar::mapPhar('default.phar')
#1 {main}
  thrown in symfony.phar on line 9

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'unable to open phar for reading "symfony.phar"' in symfony.phar on line 9

PharException: unable to open phar for reading "symfony.phar" in symfony.phar on line 9

Call Stack:
    0.0017     227224   1. {main}() symfony.phar:0
    0.0017     227920   2. Phar::mapPhar() symfony.phar:9
```

I can't find anything that helps with this.

Comment: why not using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe) from here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#book-creating-applications-without-the-installer

Comment: Try the same in a Linux VM, e.g. via Vagrant. It might be something to do with Windows - Win/PHP has got better over the last few years, but my guess is that it's still not as stable as *nix environments.

Comment: do you run this cli command with administrative privileges? http://screencast.com/t/XCyb9ieEHpq

Comment: @LPodolski Tried it. No different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason appears to be that in my Windows command prompt I was in a sub directory of `C:\Users\Me\My Documents`. Neither the symfony.phar, nor Composer will work from this directory. It has to be from `C:\Users\Me\Documents` which is the actual phsyical location, as opposed to `My Documents` which is just a virtual directory.

I don't know the technicalities of exactly why it doesn't work though.